# Open modalbox with different content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a bootstrap modalbox. The modalbox should contain different content depending which link there is clicked. The code I have made until now open the same content, but the header is working You can see a JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zdhLxwrn/)

At the moment the content text is called in both boxes. The means privacy policy and cookie policy is in both boxes.

- How can I make the link Privacy Policy only open the text of @Text for Privacy Privacy?
- How can I make the link Cookie Policy only open the text of @Text
  for Cookie Policy?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">GENERAL</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Privatpolitik">Privacy Policy</a><br/>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Cookie-Politik">Cookie Policy</a><br/>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Privatpolitik</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">@Text for Privacy Policy
                                    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                          Shouldn´t the modal content text be here?
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">@Text for Cookie Policy
                                        <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                                          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                              Shouldn´t the modal content text be here?
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the same ids to modal-body that use use in `data-whatever=""` and use this js

```
modal.find('.modal-content .modal-body').hide();
modal.find('.modal-content #' + recipient).show();
```

Also check the updated html, it had an issue so I have fixed that too. The 2 `modal-body` divs must be parallel to each other.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Modal Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">GENERAL</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Privatpolitik">Privacy Policy</a><br/>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Cookie-Politik">Cookie Policy</a><br/>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Privatpolitik</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" id="Privatpolitik">Text for Privacy Policy
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" id="Cookie-Politik">Text for Cookie Policy
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
      // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-title').text(' ' + recipient)
      modal.find('.modal-content .modal-body').hide();
      modal.find('.modal-content #' + recipient).show();
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But is the code `<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>` not needed then?

Comment: Was your issue fixed?